# Async Function MVC error 500

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to understand the async method concept, so i made a simple method that returns a View:

```
Public Async Function getPerfil() As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of ActionResult)
        Dim objOrganizacion As comOrganizacion.comOrganizacion = New comOrganizacion.comOrganizacion
        Dim ds As DataSet = Await Task.Run(objOrganizacion.GetUserPostulacion()) 
        Return View()
End Function
```

If i remove this line from the function `Dim ds As DataSet = Await Task.Run(objOrganizacion.GetUserPostulacion())`, then the method works fine and i can see the view. If i do not remove that line i get : `500 Internal Server Error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is MSDN's programming guide to asynchronicity:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

It is a lot of reading, and I can say by experience it is difficult to grasp, as I'm still trying to fully grasp it myself.  But it might help to understand if you use MVC's scaffolding that includes functions in the controller that use Await...

In calling Await [function], that function returns a Task.  For example:  an Async HttpPost function in a Controller includes the line “Await db.SaveChangesAsync()".  If you go to the definition of SaveChangesAsync(), this is what it says:

```
 Public Overridable Function SaveChangesAsync() As System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Of Integer)
 Member of System.Data.Entity.DbContext

 Summary:  Asynchronously saves all changes made in this context to the underlying database.

 Return Values:  A task that represents the asynchronous save operation.  The task result contains the number of objects written to the underlying database.
```

The save operation that it’s using being SaveChanges, this is the definition for SaveChanges:

```
 Public Overridable Function SaveChanges() As Integer
 Member of System.Data.Entity.DbContext

 Summary:  Saves all changes made in this context to the underlying database.

 Return Values:  The number of objects written to the underlying database.
```

So basically what this means is the SaveChangesAsync makes a PROMISE to the controller function to return to it what it needs once it has it.  It is like using a middle-man.  Say you need a number…well instead of telling the NumberGetter “this is what I need” and then waiting for it yourself, you tell the middle-man “this is what I need”, and then he tells the NumberGetter what you need, and waits for it himself so that you are freed up for other things in the meantime.

Now, in your context, it looks like you would want to make this call:

```
Dim ds As DataSet = Await objOrganizacion.GetUserPostulacionAsync()
```

Where objOrganizacion.GetUserPostulacionAsync() is an Async function that returns a Task(Of DataSet).  It calls the actual function (GetUserPostulacion) that will return to it the DataSet you need.

I hope that helps, anyway!